# I2C: can multiple I2C errors occur simultaneously?

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I write the driver for the I2C protocol, target microcontroller is `STM32F413ZH`.
Don't ask me why I write my own driver (this is the project requirement).

I want to create simple public API returning error state, but I wonder whether multiple I2C errors can occur at the same time. If yes, my API cannot return just single enum type, but it should return something more complex like the structure consisting of bit fields of bool type or something else.

Anyway, the main question is:

**Can multiple I2C errors occur simultaneously (at the same time)?**

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you write your own driver? It requires no justification, or excuse.  It is entirely reasinable. The STM32Cube HAL driver is abysmal, and in some versions at least buggy.

Comment: It does not need a structure, just bit masks OR'ed together.

Comment: Yeah, hard to disagree with you that HAL is buggy and poor (I totally agree and I never use it). But, many people argue that HAL (or LL) is good enough and there is no point to reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

number of I2C errors is limited (limited by the number of bits in the status register).

More than one flag can be raised by the I2C hardware so usually I use bits for the particular error enum

```
typedef enum
{
    I2C_OK      = 0,
    I2C_ERROR1  = 1 << 0,
    I2C_ERROR2  = 1 << 1,
    I2C_ERROR3  = 1 << 2,
    I2C_ERROR4  = 1 << 3,
     /* other */
}I2C_ERRORS_ENUMS;
```

Comment: I've supposed that more than one flag can be raised at the same time, but wasn't sure. Thanks!